# NVCC linking error in C and CUDA-C code

Tags: c, hyperlink, makefile, nvcc, multiple-definition-error

I'm working on an DNA Fragment Assembly program. The CPU-only version is built in C language using GCC and I'm trying to build a GPU version using NVCC.

Here is the makefile

```
all : clean FragmentAssembly.exe

FragmentAssembly.exe : Common.o Fragment.o ILS.o Consensus.o main.o
    nvcc -pg -o FragmentAssembly.exe Common.o Fragment.o ILS.o Consensus.o main.o 

Common.o : Common.cu
    nvcc -pg -o Common.o -c Common.cu

Fragment.o : Fragment.cu
    nvcc -pg -o Fragment.o -c Fragment.cu

ILS.o : ILS.cu
    nvcc -pg -o ILS.o -c ILS.cu

Consensus.o : Consensus.cu
    nvcc -pg -o Consensus.o -c Consensus.cu

main.o : main.cu
    nvcc -pg -o main.o -c main.cu

clean : 
    rm -f *.exe *.o
```

As seen, the original `.c` files became .cu files for `nvcc` to compile them correctly.
All of the cu files contain includes of their corresponding files (Common.h for Common.cu, etc..) except for `main.cu`.

ILS.h contians definition of global variables `p_instanceFragments` and `p_instanceLength`

The problem is when compiling NVCC, for an unknown reason, I get the following errors :

```
Consensus.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `p_instanceFragments'
ILS.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
Consensus.o:(.bss+0x8): multiple definition of `p_instanceLength'
ILS.o:(.bss+0x8): first defined here
```

There is no real multiple definitions since the same code is built correctly using GCC. It looks as if `ILS.h` is getting included twice in nvcc, by `ILS.cu` and `Consensus.cu`. This is also not possible since I've wrapped all my header files with an `#ifndef .. #define .. #endif` statements to avoid multiple includes and infinite include loops.

Maybe something with the makefile commands ? or should I use gcc for linking ? Can you tell me how to deal with it ?

Regards,

Comment: Without any of the code (especially the definitions of p_instanceFragments in the header file), it is more or less impossible to tell what's wrong... Just a hint: Is it possible that in `ILS.h` you used something like `int p_instanceFragments;` ? (Of course instead of `int` you probably have a more complex type). That's actually a linker problem. I guess you need to use `extern int p_instanceFragments;` in `ILS.h` and then in either `Consensus.cu` **or** (not BOTH!) `ILS.cu` you need to declare `int p_InstanceFragments;`. Of course all of this is complete guess work without code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After discussion: Here a description of what happened:

If you use gcc and you have two files (lets say `f1.c` and `f2.c`), and in both files you declare:

```
int myGlobalVariable;
```

Then the following will happen:

- When compiling `f1.c` into `f1.o`, the object file will reserve space for `myGlobalVariable`.
- When compiling `f2.c` into `f2.o`, the object file will also reserve space for `myGlobalVariable`.
- When you link both object files together, the linker will detect that there are two variables called `myGlobalVariable` and will merge these variables together.

Now it seems the `nvcc` compiler/linker is **not** able to merge these variables.

The problem was, that the file `ILS.h` declares `<some type> p_instanceFragments;`. Because `ILS.h` is included into both `ILS.cu` and `Consensus.cu`, you get this variable twice and `nvcc` complains when it has to link the application.

The solution is to declare `extern <some type> p_instanceFragments;` in `ILS.h` and then to define `<some type> p_instanceFragments;` either in `ILS.cu` **or** `Consensus.cu` (not in both).

The question [What are extern variables in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/what-are-extern-variables-in-c/1433387) has a rather extensive answer explaining all of this in detail.

Comment: Thanks. It's best detailed for beginners